# why is discord.py get_guild returning a nonetype?

Tags: python, discord.py, attributeerror

I'm running into an error in this function no matter what I try. What this function is supposed to do is remove a role from someone when they remove their reaction from a message. I'm reading the documentation on discordpy.readthedocs.io which says that bot.get_guild should return a Guild, and that you can call get_member from that Guild object. I have no idea why it thinks that guild doesn't exist. I want to understand why trying to get the guild exactly as described in the documentation returns a nonetype instead of a guild. Any guidance on how to make this function remove a member's role when they remove a reaction I would greatly appreciate.

```
@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_remove(reaction):
    if reaction.message_id == 1133426566626541568:
        index = 0
        for double in reactions:
            if double[0] == reaction.emoji.name:
                break
            else:
                index+=1
        print(reaction.guild_id)

        guild = bot.get_guild(reaction.guild_id) 
        user = guild.get_member(reaction.user_id)
        Role = discord.utils.get(user.guild.roles, name=reactions[index][1])
        await user.remove_roles(Role)
    else:
        return
```

For some godforsaken reason discord.py doesn't let you use the payload.member *specifically* if it's being removed, but still lets you get payload.user_id. Because of that I need to get the guild this is sent in with get_guild, and then use get_member in that guild to be able to change their roles. I manually tested this by removing my reaction on the message that I'm testing with this and the following error occurs:

```
2023-07-26 16:23:24 ERROR    discord.client Ignoring exception in on_raw_reaction_remove
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\goldr\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 441, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\goldr\OneDrive\Desktop\VSCode Projects\Simon's Bot\main.py", line 68, in on_raw_reaction_remove
    Role = discord.utils.get(user.guild.roles, name=reactions[index][1])
                             ^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'guild'
```

Comment: Can you try with fetch_member? Sometimes that works

Answer (score 0):

After playing around with this for a while I discovered that the members intent must be True for `guild.get_member()` to work. If you are using the default intents then this intent is not included and would require you to enable it.

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
bot = discord.ext.commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)
```

or just enabling all intents will also work..

```
intents = discord.Intents.all()
bot = discord.ext.commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)
```

I would also make sure all Privileged Gateway Intents are enabled in the discord developer portal